# reference clarification: Whitney's theorem on unique embeddability of 3-connected planar graphs?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, planar-graphs, ho.history-overview

This is a question about the correct reference for a result that seems to appear frequently in the literature on planar graph isomorphism. In ["A $V \log V$ Algorithm for Isomorphism of Triconnected Planar Graphs"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1740064), 
Hopcraft and Tarjan mention that a 3-connected planar graph has an essentially unique embedding into the plane (up to mirror symmetry), and attribute this result to Whitney (1933) ["A set of topological invariants for graphs"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371125). I've noticed this citation reappearing in various places (for example [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=804670), [here](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~nutan/papers/planarGI-ccc.pdf), and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.1896.pdf)), but I couldn't find the result in Whitney's article itself -- am I just overlooking something? The paper is dense, and builds on a series of other articles he published in succession... Still, this result sounds a lot like Theorem 11 of Whitney (1932) ["Congruent Graphs and the Connectivity of Graphs"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2371086), which states that a 3-connected planar graph has a unique dual. Was that the intended reference?

Comment: Years later, I'm having the same issue. Babai (Handbook of Combinatorics, Chapter 27, "Automorphism Groups, Isomorphism, Reconstruction") also refers to Whitney (1932) "Congruent Graphs and the Connectivity of Graphs", but I also couldn't find it in there. Another [arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.04895) I found refers to Whitney (1993) "2-Isomorphic graphs", but again I couldn't find the result in that paper. Maybe the point is that the result follows from Whitney's work, but was never stated explicitly as a theorem in his papers? Have you since been able to find the right reference?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this, and I don't remember! (I do remember having some more non-conclusive followup discussion over on the [nlab forum](https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/7955/whitneys-theorem-on-uniqueness-of-embeddings-of-3connected-graphs-in-the-plane/) shortly afterwards.). But looking again at Whitney's [2-isomorphic graphs](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2371127.pdf), I do think it is a fair reference -- the first corollary on the second page seems to state a close variant of this result in a slightly unfamiliar language.

Comment: I also had a look in Tutte's _Graph Theory_, and he gives a more recognizable statement (and proof) of this result as Theorem XI.52: "Let G be a 3-connected planar graph, not a vertex-graph, a link-graph, or a circuit. Then G has one and only one planar mesh". And he says by another result in the book, this can be identified with "Whitney's Theorem that a 3-connected planar graph can be drawn in the plane [...] in essentially only one way", citing Whitney's "2-isomorphic graphs" and the predecessor paper "Nonseparable and planar graphs".